# Pass boolean value between ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, messaging

I have to pass a boolean value from a ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB. In ViewControllerA I put as a property:

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL fromViewControllerA;
```

Then open ViewControllerB:

```
   ViewControllerB * viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];

    self.fromRootViewController = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

In ViewControllerB I imported ViewControllerA and I created the property:

```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) ViewControllerA *viewControllerA
```

later in ViewDidLoad()

```
    if (viewController.fromViewController){
       //.......
    }
```

does not work. Why?

Comment: Where do you assign anything to `viewControllerB`'s `viewControllerA` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a BOOL property in viewController B say..`BOOL setFlag`; synthesize it in ViewController B,

Now in ViewController A where you perform push

```
 ViewControllerB * viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];

    self.fromRootViewController = YES;
    viewControllerB.setFlag = YES;  //set the value here 

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you should modify your second line to **viewControllerB**.fromRootViewController? (instead of self)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the origin of your view controller you shouldn't use a property. Use a basic navigation in your navigation controllers array (in your class that want to know the origin of push).

```
NSArray *controllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
UIViewController *lastController = [controllers objectAtIndex:[controllers count]-2];
if([controller isKindOfClass:[YourDesireCheckController class]])
    return YES;
return NO;
```